# Stripe API - how to search by card fingerprint?

Tags: stripe-payments

I've got a couple of disputes in Stripe. I want to automatically refund all the charges that aren't yet disputed that came from the same card as soon as a dispute arrives. When I use the site, I can just type `fingerprint:zxcvzxcv is:captured` to the search bar and see all payments. How do I use the API the same info?

I've tried `stripe.charges.search` with `query=fingerprint:"123"` but it said fingerprint is not a supported parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
query="payment_method_details.card.fingerprint:'your-fingerprint'"
```

Documented here:
https://stripe.com/docs/search#query-fields-for-charges